# Fabric-test setup error

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to setup fabric-test repo.

While running:

```
make docker
```

command from fabric-test/fabric folder I am receiving the following error:

```
**mkdir -p .build/image/tools

Building docker tools-image

docker build  -t hyperledger/fabric-tools -f .build/image/tools/Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 44.25 MB

Step 1/13 : FROM hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:amd64-0.4.8 as builder
Error parsing reference: "hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:amd64-0.4.8 as builder" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Makefile:290: recipe for target '.build/image/tools/.dummy-amd64-1.2.0-snapshot-963ce19' failed

make: [.build/image/tools/.dummy-amd64-1.2.0-snapshot-963ce19] Error 1**
```

Has anyone faced this issue and resolved it?
I am relatively new to Hyperledger technologies.

Thanks in advance.

Edit : Resolved by updating the docker version. Older version of docker doesn't support multi-stage builds.

Comment: please put your update as an answer and then select it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by updating the docker version. Older version of docker doesn't support multi-stage builds.